# Will macOS High Sierra support my iMac's 500 GB SATA internal physical drive?

Tags: macos, mac, hard-drive, imac, high-sierra

macOS High Sierra will be released on 29.6

But, I have one issue Apple is introducing a new file system (Apple File System) which is for (Mac with all‑flash internal storage). Now as much as I know that I have a traditional Hard Drive the rotating one, so will macOS High Sierra covert my hard drive to the latest Apple File System

Comment: Tomorrow is the 26th ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, while APFS is optimized for SSDs you can still use it for HDDs as well.

Installing macOS High Sierra on a HDD installation of macOS Sierra won't prompt you to convert it to APFS, though.

See this quote from [Apple.com](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/APFS_Guide/FAQ/FAQ.html):

> Can I use Apple File System with my existing hard disk drive?
>
> Yes. Apple File System is optimized for Flash/SSD storage, but can
>   also be used with traditional hard disk drives (HDD) and external,
>   direct-attached storage.

Comment: Ok so this means my Hard Drive will be upgraded to the Latest File System!

Comment: No your hard disk will not be reformatted to APFS this answer says that you may but I have seen other links saying you won’t be able to